# Convert from Oracle function to postgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.5

Can you please help to convert below Oracle function to PostgreSQL function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TIME (DATETIME IN TIMESTAMP, TZ1 IN VARCHAR2, TZ2 IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN DATE
AS
    RETVAL DATE;
BEGIN
    RETVAL := FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'), TZ_OFFSET (TZ1)) AT TIME ZONE TZ_OFFSET (TZ2);
    RETURN RETVAL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Apart from the Oracle-style `/` suffix, this all seems standard syntax. Where specifically is the problem with running this on Postgres, did you get any errors?

Comment: I think FROM_TZ and TZ_OFFSET  functions are not there in postgreSQL

Comment: You might be looking for [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)